# tensorflowjs_converter: command not found

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'd like to convert keras model to tensorflow.js model. I run the [offical command](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html) :

```
tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                       path/to/my_model.h5 \
                       path/to/tfjs_target_dir

-bash: tensorflowjs_converter: command not found
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: PS:I have installed tensorflowjs library.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I try to install the tensorflowjs library by using:

```
 $ sudo pip install tensorflowjs
```

instead of

```
$ pip install tensorflowjs
```

and run

```
$ tensorflowjs_converter --input_format keras \
                        path/to/my_model.h5 \
                        path/to/tfjs_target_dir
```

it's running!

Answer (score 3):

In my case folder with Python binaries was not added to PATH. You can either add it to PATH or run the binary using absolute path. The following command gives the path to current Python installation you are using:

```
$ python -m site --user-base
/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7
```

Binaries will be stored in `bin` sub-dir (you can add it to PATH):

```
/Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/bin
```

To run binary using absolute path simply add a binary name `tensorflowjs_converter`:

```
$ /Users/me/Library/Python/2.7/bin/tensorflowjs_converter ...
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case creating a clean conda environment helped(pyenv doesn't suuport Windows). Make sure to use python version 3.6.8. Than activate new env and install tensorflowjs:

```
conda create -n tfjs python=3.6.8
conda activate tfjs
pip install tensorflowjs
```

It did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should install tensorflowjs library using **pip install tensorflowjs** and you better read the below documentation.
https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html

Comment: I have installed tensorflowjs library.